# Challenge Atlas Game in Python

Tags: python, performance

Here is my code:

https://gist.github.com/Salil03/5fb4d512b97324c89e2580f94725a7fd

The instructions are printed out from the python file.

They are given here for convienience

> 1. You start by typing in a letter
> 2. The computer then types another letter and the cycle repeats Example: You type: z Computer types: a
> 3. You know that zambia and zaire start with ""za""." "
> 4. So the next
>      letter you type must me ""m"" or ""i"". But, you must type" """m""
>      because the last letter of zambia will end on the computer." On the
>      other hand, last letter of zaire will end on you.
> 5. The person on which the last letter ends, loses. Example: Computer loses on sweden You lose on dubai
> 6. If you don't know any place you can type in ""Challenge""." The
>      computer will give you the answer and you will lose.
> 7. If the computer doesn't know the answer, he will say
>      ""Challenge""" Then two things can happen:
>
> 1) You know the right
>   answer and the moderator says it is correct and you win.
>
> or
>
> 2) You don't know the right answer and you type in gibberish and the
>   moderator marks it as wrong and you lose
>
> 8. Whenever you think the computer has typed in the last letter of a place, press enter.

I'm looking for comments about the following points:

1. coding style
2. performance
3. Readability of code

Comment: Welcome to Code Review.  Can you include your code also?  It is expected for reviews here.  https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @chicks The code is big so I included a link for it

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Unfortunately your question is off-topic as of now, as the code to be reviewed must be [present in the question.](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1308) Please add the code you want reviewed in your question. Thanks!

Comment: @Malachi the formatting of the code gets disturbed if I add it in the question

Comment: @Agile_Eagle: We can attempt to fix it in that case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By far the most important thing you can change is splitting your code up into smaller functions. For example, every time you print with random colors, that could be a function:

```
def print_colored(str, n=1):
    for i, x in enumerate(str):
        if i % n == 0:
                print(x, end='')
                sys.stdout.flush()
                os.system("color " + str(randint(1, 8)))
            else:
                print(x, end='')
                sys.stdout.flush()
```

Things like your main game loop can also be made a function to hide variables and make your code easier to read.

Seperation of concerns is very important in programming. In it's current state, I cant tell what is going on with out reading and understanding the entire program at once.

Comment: I will keep that in mind